# TLS error using Cockpit with Cloudflare/Portzilla

Tags: reverse-proxy, cloudflare, cockpit

I've recently installed cockpit (and quite like it) and decided to use Portzilla on my cloudflare account to set up a subdomain where I can access my cockpit server remotely. I've been getting Connection Failed errors, and when I look at `journalctl -u cockpit`, I get this:

```
Dec 26 00:27:52 helios systemd[1]: Starting Cockpit Web Service...
Dec 26 00:27:52 helios remotectl[22645]: Generating temporary certificate using: sscg --quiet --lifetime 3650 --key-strength 2048 --cert-key-file /etc/cockpit/ws-certs.d/0-self-signed.cert --cert-file /etc/cockpit/ws-certs.d/0-self-signed.cert --ca-file /etc/cockpit/ws-certs.d/0-self-signed-ca.pem --hostname helios --organization 90b1c6e4a5dc40aeb98d6ccf90a3257f --subject-alt-name localhost --subject-alt-name IP:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
Dec 26 00:27:52 helios remotectl[22645]: Error generating temporary dummy cert using sscg, falling back to openssl
Dec 26 00:27:52 helios remotectl[22645]: Generating temporary certificate using: openssl req -x509 -days 36500 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/cockpit/ws-certs.d/0-self-signed.S4R2V0.tmp -keyform PEM -nodes -out /etc/cockpit/ws-certs.d/0-self-signed.Z6R2V0.tmp -outform PEM -subj /O=90b1c6e4a5dc40aeb98d6ccf90a3257f/CN=helios -config /tmp/ssl.conf.47R2V0 -extensions v3_req
Dec 26 00:27:52 helios systemd[1]: Started Cockpit Web Service.
Dec 26 00:27:52 helios cockpit-tls[22649]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:27:52 helios cockpit-tls[22649]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:27:55 helios cockpit-tls[22649]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:27:55 helios cockpit-tls[22649]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:27:55 helios cockpit-tls[22649]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:27:55 helios cockpit-tls[22649]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:30:08 helios systemd[1]: cockpit.service: Succeeded.
Dec 26 00:34:18 helios systemd[1]: Starting Cockpit Web Service...
Dec 26 00:34:18 helios systemd[1]: Started Cockpit Web Service.
Dec 26 00:34:18 helios cockpit-tls[25787]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:34:18 helios cockpit-tls[25787]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:34:47 helios systemd[1]: Stopping Cockpit Web Service...
Dec 26 00:34:47 helios systemd[1]: cockpit.service: Succeeded.
Dec 26 00:34:47 helios systemd[1]: Stopped Cockpit Web Service.
Dec 26 00:34:47 helios systemd[1]: Starting Cockpit Web Service...
Dec 26 00:34:47 helios systemd[1]: Started Cockpit Web Service.
Dec 26 00:34:52 helios cockpit-tls[26028]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:34:52 helios cockpit-tls[26028]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:34:54 helios cockpit-tls[26028]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:36:56 helios systemd[1]: cockpit.service: Succeeded.
Dec 26 00:38:12 helios systemd[1]: Starting Cockpit Web Service...
Dec 26 00:38:12 helios systemd[1]: Started Cockpit Web Service.
Dec 26 00:38:12 helios cockpit-tls[27201]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:38:12 helios cockpit-tls[27201]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:38:13 helios cockpit-tls[27201]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:38:13 helios cockpit-tls[27201]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:38:13 helios cockpit-tls[27201]: cockpit-tls: gnutls_handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Dec 26 00:40:19 helios systemd[1]: cockpit.service: Succeeded.
```

I acknowledge the fact that cockpit is not aware of reverse proxies by default, and have to set the `cockpit.conf` accordingly, which I can provide upon request, however the required things I've seen such as the `Origins` entry (unsure if it has been done correctly) and `ProtocolHeader = X-Forwarded-Proto` have already been added to the config. I'm new to this and would love absolutely any help I can get on this. Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, that was not very helpful. Have you tried connecting directly with a modern browser?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah I've been using the latest chrome version the whole time, I haven't tested any other browsers.